# Office Add in Authentication Upgrade

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, office-js, office-addins

I am new to Azure and Office Add in. I want to migrate one of my Office add in authentication mechanism. currently the authentication is implemented using Office-JS-helpers. I want to replace this library with any other alternative. Could anyone share the best way to migrate.

- Application : Office Add in (Word and Outlook)
- Add in is written using React 16+ version
- App hosted on service fabric in azure
- Authentication enabled using Azure AD
  Note : I am Looking for SSO Authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The [Overview of authentication and authorization in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/overview-authn-authz) section in MSDN explains how to build and configure Office Add-ins to successfully implement authentication and authorization. You are interested in the following  - [Enable single sign-on (SSO) in an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But when I try to access the getAccessToken Method, Its triggering the following error.
err: OSF.DDA.Error {name: 'API Not Supported', message: 'The identity API is not supported for this add-in.', code: 13000}.
Do I need to follow all steps mentioned under Register add in with Microsoft identity platform, even though the authentication is working with office-js helpers ?

Comment: Have you followed the steps listed in the article to enable SSO? Have you register the app in Azure?

Comment: Yes I have followed the steps and registered my app in azure

Comment: following is the error when I try to access Office.auth.getAccessToken() : Invalid resource Url specified in the manifest

Comment: Did you try to run the `configure-sso` command which should be listed in the `package.json` file?

Comment: Does the manifest file contain the updated values in the `WebApplicationInfo` section?

Comment: Yes, Web application info section contains my application registration id, identification uri and scopes

Comment: package.json does not contain any configure-sso command

Comment: Try to generate a new SSO-enabled add-in skeleton using yeoman generator and see how the configure-sso command is working. Try to apply the same to your add-in.

Comment: okay, let me have a try. thanks for your time

Comment: Do I need to change my App registration supported account types from single tenant to multi tenant ? Is it mandatory, I am not sure whether this can leads to any security concerns.

Comment: Did the configure-sso command help?

Comment: Actually the app registration had some issues and after resolving the same it got resolved.

Comment: Glad to hear! Don't forget to mark the answer.